# Unable to understand SNR equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, snr

Can someone please help me understand this equation of SNR given in MATLAB:

```
SNR_dB = 1:0.1:7
SNR = 10.^(SNR_dB/10)
```

Comment: It is converting the SNR expressed in decibels to a linear (non-logarithmic) scale. Expressing the SNR in dB is convenient when plotting or in conversation, but most calculations need to be done in a linear scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express power $P$ in $\mathrm{dB}$ one performs this operation:

$$P_{\mathrm{dB}}=10\log_{10}(P)$$

The inverse operation would then be

$$\frac{P_{\mathrm{dB}}}{10}=\log_{10}(P) \implies 10^{\frac{P_{\mathrm{dB}}}{10}}=P$$

And that's exactly what you are doing in that MATLAB equation (i.e. expressing the SNR in linear scale from the data in decibels).

Note that the `.^` means that the operation is being carried out element-wise.